# Performance Issues of Redis's HMGET Command

Tags: performance, redis

When I use the Redis HMGET command to retrieve data in a production environment, if the number of keys included in the command exceeds 10,000, and there is a high volume of requests, the CPU usage of Redis spikes dramatically.

I would like to know the specific reasons behind this phenomenon, because retrieving data from a hash table should be an O(1) time expense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the number of keys included in the command exceeds 10,000

If I understand correctly, you mean the number of fields of a Redis HASH.

> retrieving data from a hash table should be O(1)

Yes, the time complexity of getting **a single field** from hash table is O(1). However, you are retrieving 10,000 fields, and the time complexity should be 10,000 times larger than O(1).

HMGET is a slow command, when the fields you need to retrieve a big number of fields. It blocks Redis, and you should use it with care on production env.